# How to read a mimedata coming from QTreeWidget in a QFrame void DragWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event), where DragWidget::QFrame

Tags: qt, qt5, qtreewidget

[debug mode image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knegw.png)

> Can anyone help me reading the text from QByteArray as iam new to Qt.
>   Also its a internal drag and drop from QTreeWidget to a QFrame. How
>   can i get the QTreeWidgetItem if i am dragging the item from
>   Qtrewidgetitem to QFrame in dropEvent function?

```
 void DragWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
    {
        if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-
    abstractitemmodeldatalist")) {
            QByteArray i

temData = event->mimeData()->data("application/x-
    abstractitemmodeldatalist");

//how to read the string from itemData//mystring is 'LDA'
```

Answer (score 1):

QByteArray encapsulates chars. Either access them directly using [] operator or use data or constData member functions that return a (const) pointer to c char array.